# Windows suddenly reports "This copy of Windows is not genuine"

Tags: windows-vista, windows-genuine-advantage

Recently, my Acer Aspire 5050 that came with a copy of Vista, went through a series of Automatic Upgrades.  Now, in the bottom of the desktop, I get "This copy of Windows is not genuine".  Apparently, because of this, I cannot open "Properties" on Computer, or open the Control Panel, etc.  This makes gathering information (like the Service Pack) difficult at best.

I've gone through several steps to prove/disprove that this is correct.  I've verified the product key by following the instructions on [MyDigitalLife.info](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/01/28/how-to-change-windows-vista-product-key/).  I did the steps with `slmgr.vbs -ipk` AND `slmgr.vbs -ato`.  This told me that my product was successfully activated.  To me, this would imply that this is a Genuine product.

I've also called the US Activation number, which gave me a response, which was successful.  Never on the phone was I given any information suggesting that the Activation code generated was invalid (I *have* been given the suggestion on an improper install of XP).

However, when I downloaded [MGADiag](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/E/7/4E713F1E-8EB8-4464-AE38-ECCFC4E19499/MGADiag.exe), it tells me that I have an Invalid License.  The product key it lists matches what I show on the bottom of the machine.  The install media was requested directly from Acer, since they didn't provide any disks initially.

Looking at the disk they sent, however, it looks like what they sent me was a Windows Anytime Upgrade disk.

Is this the correct disk?  If not, will I need to reinstall to fix the problem?  If so, does anyone know where I can get an OEM 32bit Vista ISO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acer will not be able to help you with fixing a failed WGA check, you'll have to to contact Microsoft to rectify the problem (they're the guys with the finger on the killswitch after all), the problem is quite common and MS representatives are rather helpful when dealing with the matter.

you can always install the OS from scratch, even with a Windows Anytime Upgrade disk.

here is a tutorial **[How to Do a Clean Install with a Upgrade Version of Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/68767-clean-install-upgrade-vista.html)**

once you have your Vista installation properly activated again, i recommend to backup your Vista activation files:

**[How to backup your OEM Vista activation](http://vista.blorge.com/2007/12/28/how-to-backup-your-oem-vista-activation/)**

Comment: That's the problem...  it's not actually failing the WGA check.  Everything else I've tried (http://www.vistaclues.com/this-copy-of-microsoft-windows-is-not-genuine/) suggests that it is Genuine...

Comment: Acer is the reseller, and by the OEM contract, they should be providing the support.

Comment: Acer (like any other OEM) cannot deal with WGA related issues, they do not have the means and will always refer customers MS. the OEM can provide the license key but the activation server is an exclusive Microsoft affair.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply call Acer, even outside of warranty, this is an issue that should be addressed directly by them.

We may be able to come up with a solution, but quite frankly, this should never happen (Unless you have been messing around with the registration files / "experimenting" with system files), and they should help you directly.